# What is the best way to store a JSON data object in android?

Tags: java, android, json, storage

I am developing an Android app. For this app I need to store some kind of data and access that data.

What is the best way I can store data in the Android app?

After saving somehow in Android, when a user inserts a value from the UI, the app should query the data set and check whether that value is present or not.

Please tell me how to do this in Android.

Comment: look into realm or sqlite

Comment: You can also quite easily store them as JSON strings

Comment: @KenWolf Can you explain how do i store these data as JSON strings in android?

Comment: Your options are pretty well documented here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to deal with the JSON Objects directly (althought you can if you want to). Have a look at the [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library. It serializes and deserializes JSON data into objects and makes your life much easier!

Additionally, since JSON Objects can be easily represented by strings, you can use [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store them in a key-value approach. If you end up using Gson, you can save your objects too using its `toJson()` and `fromJson()` methods.

**Note:** If you do use SharedPreferences, remember that the user can manually delete the file via the device app manager.

Comment: Hi using direct JSON objects and using a converted data set using Gson from JSON are totally 2 different methods right?

Comment: Well, kinda. It's much easier (requires less boilerplate) to read data from your objects (and much more readable as well), even though you can work with both

Answer (score 0):

You can get easier the JSON data using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) that convert the JSON to a POJO and you can save the object in SQLite, I recommend you use ORM like [SugarORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/).

Comment: We can use POJO objects without saving in SQite right?

Comment: Yeap, POJO is the object that is created by the Json, you can do what you need with it